# Como escolher qual será a chave do array em PHP e não aquela padrão (0 => ... 1 => ... 2 =>... )

Tags: php, back-end

É o seguinte, estou fazendo um pequeno sistema onde a pessoa pode incluir num array os produtos desejados, ela clica no botão do produto "Inserir" e alguns informações são colhidas desse produto e guardadas num array, no caso, o "id_produto", "nome_produto", "preco_produto", "quantidade_produto" são as informações colhidas e guardadas e nisso vai indo, a pessoa vai inserindo produtos e eles vão sendo guardados em um array. Tenho a seguinte estrutura em código:

```
case 'add':

    $produto = new ProdutoController();
    $retorno = $produto->selectId($_GET['id']);

    if (count($retorno) > 0)
    {
        foreach($retorno as $dados => $value)
        {
            $arrayProduto[$retorno[$dados]->id_produto] = array(
                                                    'id_prod' => $retorno[$dados]->id_produto, 
                                                    'nome_prod' => $retorno[$dados]->nome_produto,
                                                    'code_prod' => $retorno[$dados]->code_produto,
                                                    'preco_prod' => $retorno[$dados]->preco_produto,
                                                    'qtd_prod' => $_POST['txt_quantity']);

        }

        if(!empty($_SESSION['cart_item'])) 
        {    
            foreach ($arrayProduto as $key => $value) 
            {
                if(array_key_exists($key, $_SESSION['cart_item'])) 
                {    
                    ?> 
                        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
                        alert ("Este produto já foi inserido!") 
                        </script>
                    <?php
                        header("Location: /view/cart/cart.php");
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['cart_item'] = array_merge($_SESSION['cart_item'], $arrayProduto);
                    header("Location: /view/cart/cart.php");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['cart_item'] = $arrayProduto;
            header("Location: /view/cart/cart.php");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header("Location: /view");
    }
    break;
```

No caso, tenho a seguinte duvida:
Como faço pra eu escolher qual será a chave do array? Se eu deixar do jeito que tá, ele vai inserindo assim

```
    array (size=3)
    0 => 
    array (size=5)
          'id_prod' => string '1' (length=1)
          'nome_prod' => string 'GTX 1050 Gigabyte 2GB 128bits' (length=29)
          'code_prod' => string 'ab01' (length=4)
          'preco_prod' => string '599.90' (length=6)
          'qtd_prod' => string '1' (length=1)
    1 =>
    array (size=5)
          'id_prod' => string '5' (length=1)
          'nome_prod' => string 'VGA GTX 1070 Gigabyte 6GB 256bits' (length=33)
          'code_prod' => string 'ab07' (length=4)
          'preco_prod' => string '1399.90' (length=7)
          'qtd_prod' => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array (size=5)
          'id_prod' => string '2' (length=1)
          'nome_prod' => string 'VGA GTX 1050Ti EVGA 4GB 128bits' (length=31)
          'code_prod' => string 'ab04' (length=4)
          'preco_prod' => string '699.90' (length=6)
          'qtd_prod' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Porém eu não quero que seja estes números padrões (0, 1, 2, 3...), eu quero que seja o "id_produto" a chave do array, pra depois quando eu for excluir um produto, eu pegue o "id_prod", compare com a chave do array e onde for igual eu dou "unset", ou seja, estarei removendo. Preciso fazer a chave do array ser igual ao id_produto, como faço isso?
Obrigado!

Comment: Coloque o código responsável pelo preenchimento do array tal como o tem agora se faz favor Gabriel, para conseguir uma solução mais direcionada ao seu problema

Comment: Sou novo no stackoverflow, estava procurando o botão editar. Agora já está escrito.

Comment: Bem vindo, quando puder dê uma olhadela aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Parece-me que isso já acontece nesta linha: `$arrayProduto[$retorno[$dados]->id_produto]`, isto `$retorno[$dados]->id_produto` é o id do produto certo? Já o estar a injetar como key no `$arrayProduto`

Comment: Sim, essa parte `$retorno[$dados]->id_produto` é o id do produto escolhido, porém acontece o seguinte, veja no segundo box de código, está assim: `array (size=3) 0 => .... 1 => ...` e veja que o `'id_prod' => string '1' (length=1)` possui valor "1", eu gostaria que esse valor do 'id_prod' fosse o valor da chave do array.

Comment: É estranho, e essa box de código é o resultado `var_dump($arrayProduto);`?

Comment: Correto, postei um var_dump($arrayProduto) para ficar mais facil de visualizar. Veja neste mesmo box a seguinte parte: `array (size=3) 0 =>... 1 => ... 2 =>...` eu gostaria que estas chaves fossem iguais ao valor do campo `'id_prod'`, no caso ficaria assim:  `array (size=3) 1 =>... 5 => ... 2 =>...` (O fato do 2 ser igual ao 2 foi apenas coincidência). Ficou claro meu desejo/duvida?

Comment: Esse "size" não me aparece a mim fazendo o `var_dump(...`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php , nem aqui nos exemplos

Comment: Uai, desde que comecei a desenvolver pequenas coisas em PHP usando o wamp/sublime/mysql workbench aparece pra mim esse "size" e tbm o "length", achas que isso pode interferir em algo?

Comment: Não, não acho que isso seja relevante